# cannot implicitly convert system.data.dataset to string error in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds= new DataSet();
    sda=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from empdtl",econ.con);
    sda.Fill(ds,"empdtl");

    dataGridView1.DataMember = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = "empdtl";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass Dataset in [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and DataTable name in [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "empdtl";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```